# What is this CSS checkbox state called, and how can I remove its effects?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, pseudo-class

Consider this checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

When **pressing a keyboard button when this checkbox is focused**, a solid black outline appears around it. I can get rid of by removing the outline:

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

However, I wish to apply an outline to the actual element, and this method would invalidate it. I was wondering if there was a pseudoclass that could be used to select this checkbox state. If so, what is it called and how do I access it? If not, is there any other viable way (**CSS only**) to do achieve this? I thought the `:focused` pseudoclass would work, but this selects the focused state of the checkbox and not whatever this state is, when the checkbox is focused and a key is pressed.

P.S. when I add an outline to the checkbox, the problem appears in a different format. The **outline is somehow "extended"**, almost as if a padding or border was added to the element (try focusing on the following checkbox and pressing a key):

```css
input {
  outline: solid red 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Just inspect the element using your browser dev tools, then you will see what styles apply, and due to which selectors.

Comment: [check](https://codepen.io/markupbang-1473322092/pen/mrJxQG) ,this page will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `outline-offset: 0px;` under the element state `focus-visible` is what you're looking for:

```css
input {
  outline: solid red 3px;
}

input:focus-visible
{
  outline-offset: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The checkbox is an HTML element used to take input from the user. This HTML element is generally used on every website, but without styling them, they look similar on every website.

Comment: I am aware of this.